# How can I force my WPF main window to have a Vista look on a XP machine?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, windows-vista

I'm developing a WPF application and I wonder if it's possible for the main window to have a Vista look. Some applications like MS Live Messenger and Google's Chrome already do that.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load the "theaero.normalcolor.xaml" theme.

Here's a relevant article:

[Forcing WPF to use a specific Windows theme](http://arbel.net/blog/archive/2006/11/03/Forcing-WPF-to-use-a-specific-Windows-theme.aspx)

If you also want to change the window "furniture" (title bar, etc), check out this article:

[Custom Window Control - GlassWindow - Source Code](http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=23)

Answer (score 1):

Live Messenger and Chrome do not use WPF ;

and i m pretty sure there is no way to do it in the framework maybe you can create your own controls or at least themes for the existing ones and remeber there is no limit with WPF :)

Comment: I did not say that these apps were using WPF at all.

Comment: Yh i know what i wanted to say is that you should build everything yourself :)